# Can "assert" produce output for assertions that _pass_?

Tags: ruby, minitest

`assert(false, "statement is true")` produces output (to stdout, by default) containing the descriptive message "statement is true".  What if I want the output to also contain the descriptive message for assertions that *pass*, i.e. if I instead have `assert(true, "statement is true")`, is there an easy way to get it to send to stdout something along the lines of "asserting 'statement is true'... OK"?

Comment: why not [`refute`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-refute) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually print your message, you can define your own assertion or helper method.
Try:

```
def assert_with_message(condition, message)
  assert condition
  puts message
end
```

and:

```
assert_with_message true, "Assertion success message"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just try:

```
def assert_if(condition, message)
  assert(!condition, message)
end
```

and now:

```
assert_if true, "statement is true"
```